# Null check operator used on a null value in the method interpreter.run([input], [output]);

Tags: tensorflow

Im newbie to Tensorflow world， I learned tutorial and creat such method for text embedding, the print looks ok like this:

```
I/flutter (23098): input [10000, 10001, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 
I/flutter (23098): output check [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
I/flutter (23098): interpreter true
I/flutter (23098): inputShape: [1, 384]
I/flutter (23098): outputShape: [1, 384]
I/flutter (23098): input length: 384
I/flutter (23098): output length: 384
```

Here is my method:

```
 Future<List<double>> runModel(
      Interpreter interpreter, String inputText, List<int> inputShape) async {
    List<int> input = await stringToInputVector(inputText, inputShape[1]);

    List<int> outputShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).shape;
    List<double> output =
        List<double>.generate(outputShape[0] * outputShape[1], (index) => 0.0);

    print('input $input');
    print('output check $output');
    print('interpreter ${interpreter.isAllocated}');
    print('inputShape: ${inputShape}');
    print('outputShape: ${outputShape}');
    print('input length: ${input.length}');
    print('output length: ${output.length}');
    
    interpreter.allocateTensors();
    interpreter.run([input], [output]);
    return output;
  }

  Future<String> extractRelevantInfo(String question, List<String> historyTexts,
      Interpreter modelInterpreter, List<int> inputShape) async {
    List<double> questionVector =
        await runModel(modelInterpreter, question, inputShape);
    double maxSimilarity = -1;
    String mostRelevantText;
    for (String historyText in historyTexts) {
      List<double> historyTextVector =
          await runModel(modelInterpreter, historyText, inputShape);
      double similarity =
          await computeCosineSimilarity(questionVector, historyTextVector);

      if (similarity > maxSimilarity) {
        maxSimilarity = similarity;
        mostRelevantText = historyText;
      }
    }

    return mostRelevantText;
  }
```

But now I met error:

```
E/flutter (23098): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (23098): #0      Interpreter.runForMultipleInputs (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:196:41)
E/flutter (23098): #1      Interpreter.run (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:157:5)
E/flutter (23098): #2      TensorflowAPI.runModel (package:accounting/api_services/tensorflow_api.dart:135:17)
```

I have no idea where is this error from, here is how I use this metho, the model I tried mobilebert_1_default.tflite and albert_lite_base_squadv1_1.tflite and lite-model_universal-sentence-encoder-qa-ondevice.tflite for text embedding, all of them have this error

```
await tensorflowAPI.extractRelevantInfo(
        userQuestion, historyStrings, interpreter, inputShape);
```